# Sliding a little bit after stopping

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, game-physics

Remember playing Super Mario Bros.? When Mario moves, he runs, and then when the player stops moving, he stops, but he doesn't come to a complete stop. He slides a little bit. I need to accomplish that. Over the past 2 days, I've been completely rewriting the movement my Mario clone/platformer game, because the model I had before was inefficient and just crappy overall. Right now, I'm not sure how to continue that small bit of velocity so that the stop isn't so sudden. How would I accomplish this? All the code for movement below is in the `Player` class and the code for controls is in the `Main` class. So what can I do to detect when the player stops, and use that to add just a little bit of velocity?

Main:

```
import com.hasherr.platformer.entity.Player;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Main {

    private void display() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1000, 550));
            Display.setTitle("Unnamed Platformer Game");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // OpenGL

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60); // sync to 60 fps
            initGL();

            player.update();
            handleKeyboardInput();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private boolean keyboardInUse() {
        boolean keyboardInUse;
        if (!(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)
                || Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D) || Keyboard
                    .isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE))) {
            keyboardInUse = false;
        } else {
            keyboardInUse = true;
        }

        return keyboardInUse;
    }

    private void handleKeyboardInput() {
        if (!keyboardInUse()) {
            player.goingLeft = false;
            player.goingRight = false;
            player.resetVelocity();
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {   
            player.goingLeft = false;
            player.goingRight = true;
            player.moveRight();
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            player.goingLeft = true;
            player.goingRight = false;
            player.moveLeft();
        } else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
            player.jump();
        }

    }

    private void initGL() {
        // initial OpenGL items for 2D rendering
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 1000, 0, 550, 1, -1);

        // start rendering player image
        player.grabTexture().bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(player.xPos, player.yPos);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(player.xPos + 150, player.yPos);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(player.xPos + 150, player.yPos + 150);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(player.xPos, player.yPos + 150);
        glEnd(); // stop rendering this image
    }

    Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.display();
    }
}
```

Player:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Player {

    public Texture playerTexture;

    // Positions & speed
    public float xPos = 20.0f; // This is initial
    public float yPos = 0.0f; // Same as above.

    public float xVel, yVel;

    public static int gravityForce = 6;
    public static int jumpVelocity = 100;
    private float moveSpeed = 8.0f;
    private static int MAX_MOVE_SPEED = 25;

    public boolean isSupported = true; // Once again, initial value.
    public boolean goingRight, goingLeft, canJump;

    // movement methods & constants

    public void update() {
        applyGravity();
        checkForSupport();
    }

    public Texture grabTexture() {
        try {
            playerTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",
                    ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/test_char.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return playerTexture;
    }

    private void checkForSupport() {
        if (yPos == 0) {
            isSupported = true;
        } else if (yPos > 0 /* and is not on a platform */) {
            isSupported = false;
        }
    }

    private void applyGravity() {
        if (!isSupported) {
            yPos -= gravityForce;
        } 
    }

    public void printPos(String moveMethod) {
        System.out.println(" X: " + xPos + " Y: " + yPos + " Going Right: "
                + goingRight + " Going Left: " + goingLeft);
    }

    // movement methods

    public void resetVelocity() {
        moveSpeed = 15;
    }

    private void accelerateX() {
        moveSpeed += (float) (moveSpeed * 0.0096);
        if (moveSpeed >= MAX_MOVE_SPEED) {
            moveSpeed = MAX_MOVE_SPEED;
        }
        System.out.println(moveSpeed);
    }

    private void accelerateY() {

    }

    public void moveRight() {
        printPos("Moving Right!");
        accelerateX();
        xPos += moveSpeed;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        printPos("Moving Left!");
        accelerateX();
        xPos -= moveSpeed;
    }

    public void jump() {
        printPos("Jumping!");
        accelerateY();
        yPos += jumpVelocity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every update decrement Mario's velocity, and move mario's position by his velocity.

You should be allowing his velocity to persist across multiple updates.  Currently you're only moving mario when a left or right arrow key is depressed.  This is a fine approach, and works for some games, but now that you're wanting more physical behavior a new approach is necessary.  Time to conserve some energy!

Try this instead:

```
float acceleration = 15;
private void accelerateX(float speed) {
    moveSpeed += (float) (speed * 0.0096);
    if (moveSpeed >= MAX_MOVE_SPEED) {
        moveSpeed = MAX_MOVE_SPEED;
    }else if(moveSpeed<=-MAX_MOVE_SPEED){ moveSpeed= - MAX_MOVE_SPEED;}
}
public void moveRight() {
    printPos("Moving Right!");
    accelerateX(acceleration);
}

public void moveLeft() {
    printPos("Moving Left!");
    accelerateX(-acceleration);
}
//call this every update.
public void update(){
    float minMoveSpeed = 1;
    //snap to zero movement if movespeed is too slow.
    //this is so the player actually stops moving eventually. otherwise
    //the dampening affect would constantly shift the player to and fro.
    if(this.moveSpeed<minMoveSpeed && this.moveSpeed>-minMoveSpeed){
        this.moveSpeed = 0;
    }
    else{
        float dampening = 1f;
        //Counter velocity. this will bring mario to a halt over a number of updates
        //play with the value of dampening to get right effect.
        double sign = -(int)Math.signum(moveSpeed);
        float dampeningValue = dampening*sign;
        this.moveSpeed += dampeningValue;
    }
    xPos+= this.moveSpeed;
}
```

This code allows his velocity to persist across updates and slowing brings Mario to a stop if velocity isn't being incremented/decremented by `moveRight`/`moveLeft`.

Also you should be scaling your velocity by time so the game runs similarly on different hardware.  This is less important at this point in development; just keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, but in the update method, are you talking about the `update()` method that already exists in the `Player` class, or does this go somewhere else?

Comment: Also, by adding some of this code, the player model immediately begins to shoot across the screen to the right. Why might this be?

Comment: Okay, so I'm having some more trouble. Essentially, the code you've given me is to adjust the speed, not the velocity. The character, no matter what I do, will not stop. He just keeps sliding on ice. How do you get him to come to a complete stop?

Comment: My mistake, I fixed the code. Forgot a minus sign to reverse the addition to moveSpeed in player update.  The `update()` method I'm talking about is your display loop.

Comment: I don't see your correction. Am I blind? EDIT: My eyes are okay. The answer hadn't updated on my screen. Sorry!

Comment: It was very small. I've changed the code again to make it a bit more obvious. And I've added some code to keep the dampening from shifting the player's velocity when velocity is very small.

Comment: So what you did fixed the problem with the player going too slowly and not stopping, but the player still will keep going if left unattended and is above the minimum amount, which basically leaves us back at where we started. If I'm not touching the keyboard, he shouldn't be moving, (he should at least be stopping), not flying away.

Comment: Made another small change. Do you understand what I'm doing here and why?  That's the important part.

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding quite well, and I'm really glad you are showing me this, so thank you. I never would've thought of this, so it's good to have somebody explaining this to you.